# jquery click: how to check if the button is clicked or not clicked?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, click, onclick

How can I not to run a code if a button is clicked? For instance, this timer in my plugin will be triggered if the previous button is not clicked, but I don't want to run this timer code when the button is clicked.

```
$.fn.run_slide.timer_each = setTimeout(function() {
    $.fn.run_slide.loop_slide(object);
},o.timerEach);
```

This timer code is inside this chunk of code,

```
next.css({opacity: 0.0}).addClass('active').animate({opacity: 1.0}, o.timerTransition, function(){

    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, o.timerTransition).removeClass('active last-active');

    $.fn.run_slide.timer_each = setTimeout(function() {
        $.fn.run_slide.loop_slide(object);
    },o.timerEach);


});
```

I was thinking to do something like this but I think it is not the right method,

```
if(!button_previous.click)
{
$.fn.run_slide.timer_each = setTimeout(function() {
        $.fn.run_slide.loop_slide(object);
    },o.timerEach);
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

found the problem in my code and this is my solution:

```
// Check if the next button or previous button is not clicked then fade the current slide.
 if(!button_previous.click) current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, o.timerTransition).removeClass('active last-active');
```

Comment: Why don't you just run the code normally until the button is clicked?

Comment: I thought of that but how do I stop the code when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop a timeout from being executed the next time by using clearTimeout(), passing the setTimeout() handler as a parameter.

Should be something like this

```
clearTimeout( $.fn.run_slide.timer_each );
```

But I'm not sure if you sticked the setTimeout handler in a good position.

Comment: thanks. my timer is fired after the animate function and the click function could happen before, or after, or in-between the time of animate. but I think I found the problem and fixed it in my edit.

Comment: you could also set a variable or add a class (or a data) to the button when this gets clicked... and when the timeout function gets executed, check if the button has that particular class/data or what that variable value is, and stop the function with a return statement for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use clearTimeout, as demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/BJjX4/1/).